# Bat&Ball puzzle

Tags: prolog

I am trying to solve this puzzle in prolog:

> A bat and ball cost $1.10. The bat costs one dollar more than the
>   ball. How much does the ball cost?

```
solve(Bat, Ball, Sum) :-
  Bat + Ball is Sum,
  Bat is 1 + Ball.
```

I came up with this potential solution, however I am getting false with no answer.

Here's my query:

```
solve(Bat, Ball, 1.10).
```

I would also like to understand, what's wrong with my reasoning here.

Comment: `Bat + Ball is Sum`... `is/2` doesn't work this way. `is/2` evaluates the 2nd argument and binds it to the 1st. So the first must be a single, bindable variable. Anything else will fail automatically. No the other way around. Also, it doesn't know how to solve for multiple variables. For that, use CLP(FD): `Bat + Ball #= Sum` and `Bat #= 1 + Ball`. You'll need the directive, `:- use_module(library(clpfd)).`

Comment: @lurker thanks! 2 things I noticed - it's not intended to work with decimal numbers - I had to use 110 in this case (but no big deal) - other thing is I get this strange output and not real answer:  my query: `?- solve(Bat, Ball, 110).`
answer: `1+Ball#=Bat,
Bat+Ball#=110.`. I would like to get answer for example - `Bat: 105, Ball: 5`

Comment: That is correct. CLP(FD) is for integers only. Fortunately, in this case, you can scale it to integers as you noted. Look up CLP(FD) and you find you can constrain the values to certain domains (obviously the numbers should be constrained as non-negative and neither can exceed the sum). Then use labeling to get concrete results. Prolog does most of the work for you here.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you would need to implement commercial rounding too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way, by generate and test:

```
cents(Cents) :- between(0,1 000 000,Cents).

bat_and_ball(Bat, Ball, Sum) :-
  cents(Ball),
  Bat is 100 + Ball,
  Sum is Bat + Ball.
```

Of course, learn CLP(FD) instead, to progress in your Prolog study.

*note*: @lurker does a *great* job to *really* explaining your fault. So credits to him...